# echo plus sign php

Tags: php, string, echo

I'm echoing a php string variable into html

```
<span class="title_resource">
  <?php echo  $titulo; ?>
</span>
```

But when the plus sign (+) is present, it turns into a space.

I've already tried using urlencode but then I get something like "Constru%25C3%25A7%25C3%"

Should I use something like string replace?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

$titulo is setted using $_GET

```
if (isset($_GET['T']))// title
    $titulo = $_GET['T'];
```

(...)

More **clear**, perhaps

I want to send exactly this text "Estudo de ax^2 + bx + c". The page receives by $_GET. When I print this value I get "Estudo de ax^2 bx c"

Comment: what is the value of `$titulo` ?

Comment: Try using `urldecode()`.

Comment: i think you have a `+` sign in your string and you want to echo the same sign with `+`??

Comment: I can't repeat the case.. how are you getting this problem?

Comment: urldecode prints the string without the '+' :(

Comment: @Starx basically, I receive the variable through $_GET, then I all want is to print it back, with all the characters, but the '+' isn't showing

Comment: what is the value of $_GET['T']?

Comment: Let me be clear about this, you send `some text` from the from, its changes to `some+text` in the url, and you want read the value as `some+text` not `some text`

Comment: @Starx I want to send exactly this text "Estudo de ax^2 + bx + c". The page receives by $_GET. When I print this value I get "Estudo de ax^2 bx c"

Comment: Check my answer, may be it will help

Comment: The real problem here is that the `+` is not encoded on the calling page. $_GET should really contain `Estudo+de+ax^2+%2B+bx+%2B+c`.

Comment: @cbuckley Yes, you are absolutely right. I've managed to call javascript encodeUriComponent to send encoded pluses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the way values as encoded to be sent over using GET, spaces are converted to `+` and `+` are converted to `%2B`.

If you really want to send the plus symbol over the form, then replace the spaces with plus

```
$text= str_replace(" ", "+", $text);
```

Next make sure your form uses correct `enctype` either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using `urldecode` not `urlencode` ...

```
<span class="title_resource">
  <?php echo  urldecode($titulo); ?>
</span>
```

If this does not work ... can you add the full script .. where you passing , are you using POST etc .. so that i can help you better

:)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your variable is going through [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)